# Error of object required, running error 424

Tags: excel, vba

My error comes at the definition of LR. It is error object required 424. Anyone knows the problem?

```
Sub
Dim LR As Long
Dim FLR As Long
LR = wb.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List").Cells(Row.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
FLR = wb.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List").Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

wb.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List").Cells(FLR, 1).Value = "19"
wb.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List").Cells(FLR, 1).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & FLR & ":" & "A" & LR)
End Sub
```

---

After Rectification:

There is Error in `Selection.Autofill` in the Below code now.

```
Sub tst()

Dim LR As Long
Dim FLR As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'assuming you want your code to run in

With wb.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List")

LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
FLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1

.Cells(FLR, 1).Value = "19"
.Cells(FLR, 1).Select

Msgbox LR & "  " & FLR

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A" & FLR & ":A" & LR)

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no procedure name. Also  `Wb` is not declared as workbook and not set.

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

- No declaration of wb
- Wrong formula `row.count`

**Try this:**

```
Sub tst()

Dim LR As Long
Dim FLR As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'assuming you want your code to run in

With wb.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List")

LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
FLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1

.Cells(FLR, 1).Value = "19"
.Cells(FLR, 1).Select

Msgbox LR & "  " & FLR

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A" & FLR & ":A" & LR)

End With

End Sub
```

I have cleaned up your code as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but there is still runtime error 1004 at selection autofill section.

Comment: Try Now. Edited the Answer. Also check what values are `LR` & `FLR`. It should be `.Range`

Comment: And FYI, i solved the issue you mentioned in the Question.

Comment: But it is still runtime error 1004 at at selection autofill section

Comment: You want to autofill from `A1:A` ??

Comment: Use the Above code and tell me what you get in Msgbox

Comment: I want to autofill from (column a and one row below last row used) to (column a and same row with column b) There is a error 1004 here.

Comment: I used the above code and get error 1004 at autofill section. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You should get a Msgbox displaying the value of LR & FLR. tell me what values you are getting

Comment: The value is the next row of last used row number for LR and last row number of second column for FLR.